# Initialize @NSManaged variables in an NSManagedObject class?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, initialization, nsmanagedobject

I am in the process of converting a project written in `Swift` to use `CoreData`. Everything is working fine except now I am trying to convert a custom class to an `NSManagedObject` class to store it's properties in `CoreData`. It looks something like this:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class Jar: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var jarDescription: String
    @NSManaged var jarType: UIImage
    @NSManaged var progress: Int
    @NSManaged var jarSize: Int

    /*
    init() {

        name = "Some Jar"
        jarType = UIImage(named: "EmptyJar3.png")
        progress = 0
        jarSize = 60
        jarDescription = ""

   */

}
```

I have commented out the `init()` because from what I have read you can't use an initializer method on an `NSManagedObject`. However I have code elsewhere in my project that instantiates an object of type `Jar`, and for properties that are not explicitly set for this class, I want to have some sort of default initial values set for these properties.

Is there a way to do this inside the `class Jar: NSManagedObject`? It seems it would get very confusing if I was writing check methods to see if properties were set, and then explicitly saving them to `CoreData`, everywhere I instantiated a new `Jar` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are porting the app from Objective-C, then why not just do what you ObjC code does (obviously, it does not implement -init).

You **can** provide your own custom init method, but you must ensure that `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` is called appropriately and you better read the documentation carefully.

You **can** override `awakeFromInsert` and/or `awakeFromFetch` but you should be aware of some of the idiosyncrasies involved in doing so.

I have found that, in general, if you want special initialization to happen, then you are better off writing factory methods.  I'm sure you can do the same with "class methods" in swift, but I've yet to have a reason to write any swift, so I don't know swift, and so I'll give the example in ObjC, and you can interpret the rest.

For example...

```
+ (NSString*)entityName
{
    return @"Jar";
}

+ (instancetype)jarWithName:(NSString*)name
                  imageName:(NSString*)imageName
                       size:(NSUInteger)size
     inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    Jar *jar = [NSEntityDescription
        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[self entityName]
                 inManagedObjectContext:context];
    jar.name = name;
    jar.jarDescription = @"";
    jar.jarType = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    jar.progress = 0;
    jar.jarSize = size;
    return jar;
}

+ (instancetype)jarInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    return [self jarWithName:@"Some Jar"
                   imageName:@"EmptyJar3.png"
                        size:60
      inManagedObjectContext:context];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the NSManagedObject's `awakeFromInsert` method to populate default values.  See the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/awakeFromInsert)

Comment: Be **very** careful if using `awakeFromInsert`, especially if using them with parent/child MOCs, as it can be called multiple times for the "same" object - note it's not the exact same object, because it's in different managed object contexts, but it's the same logical object.